# NHibernate.ISession.CreateCriteria(typeof(BusinessObject)) is {}

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

In my code, While the session is open and connected, after invoking the List() method:

```
        using (ISession NSession = SessionProvider.GetSession())
        {
            ICriteria CriteriaQuery =
                NSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Application));
             return (List<Application>) CriteriaQuery.List<Application>();
        }
```

it is not retrieving any data and just a "{}", This is the Application Class and its mapping XML code:

```
public class Application
{
     private string _name;
     private Developer _developer;
     private int _id;
     private List<Bug> _bugs;

    public Application()
    {
        _bugs = new List<Bug>();
    }

    public virtual int ApplicationId
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public virtual Developer Developer
    {
        get { return _developer; }
        set { _developer = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public virtual List<Bug> Bugs
    {
        get { return _bugs; }
        set { _bugs = value; }
    }
}
```

And:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="BugTracker.Model"
                   assembly="BugTracker">
  <class name="Application" table="Applications" lazy="false">
    <id name="ApplicationId" column ="ApplicationId" type="int" unsaved-value ="0">
      <generator class ="native"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name ="Name" column="Name"/>

    <component access ="field.camelcase-underscore" name ="Developer"
               class="Developer">
      <property access ="field.camelcase-underscore" 
                column ="DeveloperFirstName" name="FirstName"/>
      <property access ="field.camelcase-underscore" 
                column="DeveloperLastName" name="LastName"/>
    </component>

    <bag cascade="all-delete-orphan"
          inverse ="true"
          name ="Bugs"
          lazy="false"
          access ="field.camelcase-underscore">
      <key column ="ApplicationId"/>
      <one-to-many class ="Bug"/>
    </bag>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that exception happens in the last line of the application class constructor!

Answer (score 0):

you sure dont get an Exception on `return (List<Application>) CriteriaQuery.List<Application>();`?

as far as i know, nhibernate needs interfaces for collections, so it can plug in its own changetracking. Can you try and change `List<Bug>` to `IList<Bug>`

Comment: Yes I did and still I get that exception! Surely I am getting a cast exception and that return line is causing that exception.

Comment: I did change the list to Ilist, still the same!

Comment: @FidEliO which exception are you getting now?

Comment: Message:Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of BugTracker.Model.Application

Comment: @FidEliO you changed the backing field from `List<Bug>` to `IList<Bug>` too?

Comment: wat do u mean by backing field?

Comment: `private List<Bug> _bugs;` to `private IList<Bug> _bugs;`